# Pycharm import statement is gray, but it's being used and is necessary ?

Tags: python, import, pycharm, gis, qgis

One of my import statements

```
from qgis.core import *
```

is gray in pycharm, however it's still being called upon. If I remove the import statement my script no longer works. I was just ignoring this issue but I'm trying to compile my script via pyinstaller and it's giving me errors, which lead me to believe it has something to do with this strange import.

Has anyone else encountered this? Also anyone else have advice for compiling a script that uses qgis.core? It has not been easy.

Comment: You imported the star, so you probably are not using everything in that module

Comment: possibly, however everywhere I use that module in the code is underlined red, like the module hasn't been imported. It still works though?

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, then